# How do i get past this certificate error?

Tags: google-chrome, error

On Google Chrome, i want to go to a website, which is blurred out for privacy reasons, but whenever i click proceed anyway, it tells me on and on the same message, can someone help me out or something or how do i add that website as a administrator website, or a trusted website? Im using a mac machine.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to give you a fish here but since you don't want to share the hostname... the error indicates that the name in the address bar (eg. apple.stackexchange.com) does not match anything in the certificate that the site is presenting (perhaps it actually belongs to some.bogus.example.tld).

I think it's rather a poor idea to defeat the safety measures Google put in there for you. May I ask your reasoning for being fearless here?

Comment: FWIW note that the second error indicates that the certificate itself was not issued by a known certificate issuer and so it might have been cobbled together by a bad guy in order to get "https://" to show up in the address bar. Fortunately the Goog is giving you every chance not to get hurt here.

Comment: Somehow i got it fixed by adding it to trusted sites... Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: good luck to you

Comment: Certainly not wanting to offend! I meant good luck because adding a certificate that is untrusted and does not match the host you're going to is reckless if you don't know why you had to do it. It's a genuine expression of concern.